# Jquery / imagemap combination not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

I'm using a combination of Jquery and html imagemap to have a banner with rollovers over different areas. The basic function of it works fine, but I've been having issues with making it more advanced.

This is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2fav4/

What's happening, is the hover works fine, the new image appears and all that. When the user clicks on the image, it stays up (like it's supposed to), the problem is that the clicked state never goes away. I want the user to be able to dismiss the image by clicking it a second time.

Comment: You need to use absolute urls to your images so they show up in the fiddle. I.e. the url where the images are stored.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it all runs fine now.

Comment: Then you should either delete the question or put your solution down below and accept it for others.

Comment: Sorry, meant the jsfiddle was working, the question still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use `.toggleClass()`.

Simplifying significantly, I get:

```
jQuery("#map-container area").mouseover(function() {
    jQuery('.'+$(this).attr('id')+'-map').show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    jQuery('.'+$(this).attr('id')+'-map').not('.selected').hide();
}).click(function(){
    var regionMap = jQuery('.'+$(this).attr('id')+'-map');
    jQuery('#map-container img.region').not(regionMap).removeClass('selected').hide();
    regionMap.toggleClass('selected').not('.selected').hide();
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPg4D/1/)

You will see that I removed everything to do with `....list` as it's non-functional, at least in the HTML I can see. If list stuff is important, you will have to add it back in.

Comment: Or maybe like [this slightly different version](http://jsfiddle.net/PPg4D/2/) - without mousing-off, click repeatedly on an active area and you will see the difference.

Comment: One other thing, how about some blue cows?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not the graphic designer, just a lowly developer :P